# Globally override postMessage

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to monkey patch postMessage for any new instance of a window and all the ways it can be obtained?

patching window.postMessage for example will not do anything to
frame.contentWindow.postMessage

Is there a prototype to override?
Thanks

Comment: `window.__proto__.postMessage` is `undefined`, at least in Firefox.